# How to fix external_links not working in docker-compose version 2.12.2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The version of docker is 25.0.3, the version of docker-compose I'm using is 2.12.2, and I'm using external_links in my docker-compose.yml file, but when I use
`docker-compose up -d`, the external_links are not working, because diagnose_worker is not linked to any service.

The content of docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  alfa_service:
    image: "docker-harvor/alfa_service:${CHATGPT_VERSION}"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - openai_net
    runtime: nvidia
    environment:
      - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:${CM_FASTAPI_PORT}:8000"
      - "0.0.0.0:${CM_GRPC_PORT}:50051"
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "${LOG_DIR}/trtservice:/var/log/supervisor/trtservice"
 
  web:
    image: "docker-harvor/web_service:${CHATGPT_VERSION}"
    restart: always
    cap_add:
      - SYS_TIME
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:${CM_WEB_PORT}:8080"
    networks:
      - openai_net
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone"
      - "/proc/sysrq-trigger:/sysrq"
      - "${SWIFT_DIR}:/mnt:ro"
      - "${LOG_DIR}:/var/log/proscan"
      - "${DATA_DIR}:/opt/proscan"
    environment:
      - TZ=${SYS_TIME_ZONE}
    external_links:
      - mysql:${CM_MYSQL_HOST}
      - redis:${CM_REDIS_HOST}
      - rabbitmq:${CM_CELERY_HOST}
      - oss:${CM_SWIFT_HOST}

  diagnose_worker:
    image: "docker-harvor/diagnose_worker:${CHATGPT_VERSION}"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - openai_net
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "${LOG_DIR}/worker:/var/log/supervisor/worker"
      - "${LOG_DIR}:/var/log/proscan"
    external_links:
      - mysql:${CM_MYSQL_HOST}
      - redis:${CM_REDIS_HOST}
      - rabbitmq:${CM_CELERY_HOST}
      - oss:${CM_SWIFT_HOST}
    links:
      - alfa_service:${CM_PROSCAN_HOST}
      - web:${CM_WEB_SERVICE}

  nginx:
    image: "docker-harvor/nginx_proxy:${CHATGPT_VERSION}"
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "${LOG_DIR}/system:/www/data/logs"
      - "${LOG_DIR}/nginx:/var/log/nginx"

networks:
  openai_net:
    external: true
```

The first question:

Which version of docker-compose should docker 25.0.3 correspond to?

The second question:

What is the difference between docker-compose and docker compose?

The third question:

I have installed docker-compose on the server , its version is 2.12.2 and also installed docker compose, its version is 2.24.5, when I use docker compose to start docker-compose.yml, the external_links are in effect. And when I use docker-compose to start docker-compose.yml, external_links is not valid. Which version of docker-compose do I need to use?

The fourth question:

From which version does docker support the docker compose command?

Comment: `docker` and `docker-compose` are not synonymous, they must be installed separately or via Docker Desktop (which simplifies some boilerplate installation). You really need to show your docker and compose files as well (if you are having issues with compose) as the output from the console showing the error. This question (in my opinion) is hard to follow

Comment: I added the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Docker links are an obsolete option from first-generation Docker networking.  You should delete all of the `links:` and `external_links:` options.  Make sure to use the Compose service names `web` and `alfa_service` as host names for connections between containers; don't try to create a network-level mapping to other names.  You also may want to see [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects) for details on the Compose networking setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze，I use docker run to start a mysql container, and then I need to use this mysql container in my docker-compose.yml file. If I do not use external_links in the docker-compose.yml file, what should I do?

Comment: Best option is to move the database container into the same Compose file as the application that uses it.  Second-best option is to start the database container with a `docker run --net` option so that it's on the network Compose creates.

Comment: I'm sorry, @DavidMaze is much more experienced in these situations as me (pretty sure he's even given me answers), but in my opinion you need to configure your `docker-compose` to run and communicate with all contained services. The idea you aren't simply using `docker-compose` to run your whole environment seems wrong, for the fact you use `docker-compose`. Again, in my use case both in dev, staging, and prod, my uses are contained in some type of `docker-compose.yml` file for everything...outside of obviously building my containers with a Dockerfile

Comment: @David Maze and @ViaTech，Nowadays, when installing docker, the docker compose command is installed by default, is there any correspondence between the versions of docker and docker compose?