# Create local network with multiple Docker compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I would like to create a local network for development. Most for experimental purposes and homework. The idea is to replicate a typical network that is created in an office or even in most cases in production environments.

The requirements for such a network are very simples

1. All the services shall have a static IP Address
2. There's only one service that can interact with the docker host. That is, is visible to host with a specific dns name or simply with `http://(localhost):(port)`
3. the network may be used in multiple docker compose files
4. the network shall allow outbound traffic to internet for all the services but for inbound only the `proxy` service shall receive traffic from the host.

In this [picture](https://yuml.me/ab01f56d.png) there is a very simple representation of the network. please note that I only want to include the orange and red boxes in the network

### Implementation

I wish to use two docker compose files to describe the implementation

1. backend servers (sql database, caching, etc.)
2. application services (apis and others)

#### Backend servers

For backend servers I have created a docker compose file which I summarize in the following

```yaml
version: "3.8"

networks:
  my-backend-network:
    name: my-network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.90.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.90.0.1

services:
  sql-database:
    [... other configs removed for brevity ...]
    networks:
      my-backend-network:
        ipv4_address: 10.90.1.11
```

#### Application services

For application services I have created a different docker compose file which I summarize in the following

```yaml
version: "3.8"

networks:
  my-apps-network:
    external: 
      name: my-network

services:
  proxy:
    [... other configs removed for brevity ...]
    ports:
      - "9001:80"
    networks:
      my-apps-network:
        ipv4_address: 10.90.2.11
  api-service-2:
    [... other configs removed for brevity ...]
    ports:
      - "9101:80"
    networks:
      my-apps-network:
        ipv4_address: 10.90.2.12
```

This configuration works however it is not exactly what I wanted to achieve. In details:

- Every single API service can also be reached by the docker host which is something I would like to avoid
- The proxy, which is correctly reached by the docker host through http://localhost:9001 is not able to route through the internal network using internal docker names. I mean for example: `http://localhost:9001 -> http://api-service-2:80`

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects) but it sounds to me that the real problem is to allow the proxy service to be able to route through two different network. Which I don't really understand how to implement it

Comment: This setup doesn't quite match normal Docker networking, or typical practices.  Without doing anything special with Compose `networks:`, a container can't be reached from the host unless it specifies `ports:`.  Docker can assign non-conflicting IP addresses on its own, these addresses aren't reachable from outside containers, and within Docker there's an internal DNS system; you shouldn't ever need to manually specify container IP addresses.  Finally, it's common to put both an application and its database in the same Compose file.  Would a much simpler setup work for you?

Comment: [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects), which you link to, does describe how to either allow the reverse proxy to call multiple per-project Compose networks, or group all of the projects into the same single network so the proxy can reach them.  Make sure to delete the `ports:` for the services you don't want to be directly reachable.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know why, apparently there's no connection between the topics, but removing the `ports` configuration made it working also point #2 of my question. If you write it as an answer I can accept it. With regards to your first comment: yes it would have worked, as I wrote at the beginning of the question I am just experimentig with some more difficult use cases. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish most of what you're asking for with only basic Docker options.

> There's only one service that can interact with the docker host. [...] `http://(localhost):(port)`

Containers are normally accessible from outside Docker only if they have `ports:` declared.  These aren't required (or used) for connections between containers.  So for the single service that can receive inbound connections, declare `ports:`, but delete them from every other container.

> the network shall allow outbound traffic to internet for all the services but for inbound only the `proxy` service shall receive traffic from the host.

This is standard Docker behavior, provided `ports:` are set up as above.

> the network may be used in multiple docker compose files

You can assign an explicit name to Compose networks if required.  In particular, this means that you can give an explicit name to the `default` network.  See [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation, especially the "Configure the default network" and "Use a pre-existing network" sections.

> All the services shall have a static IP Address

You never need this.  From outside Docker, the container-internal IP addresses are usually unreachable, whether you specify them directly or not.  Between containers, so long as they're on the same network, Docker provides DNS service that lets you look up another container's IP address by name.

(Compare this to a physical network.  Again, it's common to use DHCP to dynamically assign IP addresses to hosts, and the network-management layer ensures the assigned addresses don't conflict.)

---

Let's map this to the example you show above.  You declare the network in the "backend" file, which is fine.  If its Compose name is `default`, then containers that don't declare `networks:` will automatically attach to it.

```yaml
# backend/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
networks:
  default:             # name "default" is important
    name: my-network
    # external: false  # standard setting, Compose will create the network
services:
  sql-database:
    image: ...
    # no ports:, so unreachable from outside Docker
    # no networks:, so uses the default network
    # automatically assigned non-conflicting IP address
```

```yaml
# services/docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"

networks:
  default:            # "default" name is important
    name: my-network  # matches the other file
    external: true    # don't create the network

services:
  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    ports:
      - "9001:80"     # <-- this is the single visible service
    # no networks:, so on the default network with an automatic IP address
  api-service-2:
    build: ./service_two
    # no ports:, so not accessible from outside Docker
    # no networks:, so on the default network with an automatic IP address
```

With this setup, the proxy service could use something like an Nginx `proxy_pass http://api-service-2` directive to reach the backend on the default unencrypted HTTP port 80, and the backend could use something like `sql-database:5432` in its configuration to reach the database on the standard PostgreSQL port.