Docker can't connect my mysql container with djngo container
I have two separate container. When I am trying to connect MySQL with my Django container I am getting this error:
    django_farhyn  |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    django_farhyn  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005,

 "Unknown server host 'mysql' (-2)")  

This docker compose file for mysql , phpmyadmin and using for others services:
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always

This docker compose file for only django project
version: '3'

services:
  django_farhyn:
    build: .
    container_name: django_farhyn
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"  # Django application port mapping

here my db settings:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config('MYSQL_DATABASE', default=''),
        'USER': config('MYSQL_USER', default=''),
        'PASSWORD': config('MYSQL_PASSWORD', default=''),
        'HOST':   'mysql',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

I don't know where I am doing mistake and struggling from few hours for connect mysql container with my django docker container.

please provide the django configuration and also info on how you're running the django instance. is it containerized?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects

If you can move everything into the same Compose file, that's the easiest setup here.

It looks to me like you have 2 docker-compose files and you need connectivity between the 2 docker-compose networks. By default docker-compose won't allow any connectivity from other docker(-compose) applications outside it's own network.
You'd need to setup a network that allows external connections in your main docker-compose file like this:
main docker-compose.yml
networks:
  default:
    name: mysql

Django docker-compose.yml
networks:
  default:
    name: mysql
    external: true

Something like this should work, also check the docs for more info:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
