Can't establish a TCP connection between the gateway and a microservice with Docker and NestJS
I'm new to Docker. I'm making a library website and trying to create a TCP connection between a gateway and a microservice using NestJS, but I can't make it work. Both projects have their own Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. The microservice also uses a database.
I've tried setting host to the service names, creating a network and specifying that network in networks in docker-compose.yml, but nothing works. Moreover, when I use networks, the microservice can't connect to its database.
Gateway
Dockerfile:
FROM node:22.7
WORKDIR /gateway
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  gateway:
    image: library-gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm run start:dev

catalog.module.ts:
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      { name: 'CATALOG', transport: Transport.TCP, options: { port: 3001 } },
    ]),
  ]
})
export class CatalogModule {}

Catalog (microservice)
Dockerfile:
FROM node:22.7
WORKDIR /catalog
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=$DATABASE_NAME
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DATABASE_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  catalog:
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    image: library-catalog
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    command: npm run start:dev

volumes:
  db:

main.ts:
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    { transport: Transport.TCP, options: { port: 3001 } },
  );

  await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();


Does Communication between multiple docker-compose projects include a setup that works for you?  If these two services are part of the same larger project, does it make sense to run them both from the same Compose file?

@DavidMaze Thanks for the link. I commented out all the code related to my database and was able to make the services talk to each other according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42114724/26622624. However, when I include the database back, the connection stops working.

The database seems to be healthy. I can access it directly with sh.

I was unclear in my first comment. The connection stops working because catalog can't connect to the database and stops initializing.

For two things to communicate, they have to have networks: in common.  If a service doesn't say anything else, it gets networks: [default], where each Compose file has its own separate default network unless you configure it separately.

@DavidMaze They communicate if I create a single network for all three services. However, right now my goal is to create two networks, one for the microservice and its database, and one for the gateway and all the other things it will be connected to (those things will have their own networks too). I managed to set up a connection between the database and the microservice, but still can't get the gateway to talk to the microservice, even though if I inspect the network, they are there.

Here's the error message from node when trying to talk to the microservice: https://i.imgur.com/EMmi1fR.png. Here's the network for the gateway and catalog: https://i.imgur.com/RAwcNvM.png. Here's the one for the catalog and database: https://i.imgur.com/o4oAZfg.png

I've just tried installing ping on the gateway container, and it can see the catalog, but if I use Postman with 'http://localhost:3000/genre' (should return an empty array), it throws an error as before.

Changing host from catalog to 0.0.0.0 in main.ts in the microservice repository fixed the issue. In the gateway repo the host is still catalog.
