# Save results from terminal in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am having trouble output/saving the results from my terminal commands.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Process
Suite Teardown      Terminate All Processes     kill=True

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Run Process   adb devices -l
```

**Current Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

However, if i just run adb devices -l, it will provide me with a list of android devices id.

E.g. List of devices attached
0429329319 device usb: xxxx

**My attempts**

1. Based on the robot framework, it has this example that i tried to follow but gave me errors such as *"No keyword with name ${result} = Run Process found"*

Sample code from robot framework

```
${result} = Run Process program stdout=${TEMPDIR}/stdout.txt    stderr=${TEMPDIR}/stderr.txt
Log Many    stdout: ${result.stdout}    stderr: ${result.stderr}
```

2. Another way that i have discovered is to use 'Get Process Result' keyword.

So my question is - how do i print/save the output of my terminal commands?

Would appreciate if anyone can take a look at it

**Referenced to**

- http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html
- https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/atest/testdata/standard_libraries/process/get_process_result.robot

Comment: where is code you tried? _ it has this example that i tried to follow_ after this there is only error not a code you tried.

Comment: Hi @Dev , thanks for ur response! I just found out the answer to my question. Will be updating this answer section shortly :)

Comment: the error ` "No keyword with name ${result} = Run Process found"` means you only have a single space after `=`. You need to have two or more spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out one way would be using the OperatingSystem library - 'Run'.

Then log the results of the command entered into the terminal/command prompt using 'Log To Console'

```
*** Settings ***
Library             OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Get list of devices
    ${result} =     Run     adb devices -l
    Log To Console  [${result}]
```

To save the printed stuff in the console, just do
*robot xx.robot > console.txt*

Referenced to - [how to run commands in CMD prompt using robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851850/how-to-run-commands-in-cmd-prompt-using-robot-framework)