# How do I start cmd using robotframework?

Tags: python-3.x

How to start cmd from system using robotframework (Language- python)

My Python version is 3.9.7
robotframework version 6.0
pip version 20.3.4

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this library:
[Robot Framework Operating Systems Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html)

Type this into the search bar: "start command prompt with robot framework": [how to run commands in CMD prompt using robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851850/how-to-run-commands-in-cmd-prompt-using-robot-framework)