# How to get the local IP address of a DHCP client host from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, dhcp

To get the local fixed IP address, I use:

```
IP_ADDRESS = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
```

When I run this command on a DHCP client host, it returns `'127.0.1.1'`.

I know how to get it by parsing the result of `ifconfig`, but I would prefer to get it directly from python. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib The problem will be that you can have multiple interfaces - the second answer provides you the address of the first interface with internet access (here: checking Google's free DNS server).

Comment: Thanks, I found an answer that works in both DHCP and non DHCP host: `[(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]`.