# Get current server ip or domain in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a util method in Python Django project:

```
def getUserInfo(request):

    user = request.user
    user_dict = model_to_dict(user)
    user_dict.pop("password")
    user_dict.pop("is_superuser")
    user_dict["head_img"] = user.head_img.url # there is `/media/images/users/head_img/blob_NOawLs1`
```

I want to add my server domain or ip in the front of it, like:

```
http://www.example.com:8000/media/images/users/head_img/blob_NOawLs1
```

How to get current server ip( or domain )?

---

**EDIT**

I am not going to get the remote ip, I just want to get the server ip. I mean, I write the Django as backend server, when it is running, how can I get the server ip? or domain.

Comment: refrer here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/6Fjb5FOFrgg .  try this :                                                                                   
    import socket
    socket.gethostbyname(request.META['SERVER_NAME'])

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the hostname from the request like this ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host)):

```
request.get_host()
```

and the remote IP of the client like this ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)):

```
request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

To get the **server** IP is a bit tricky, as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166520/719247),
which gives this solution:

```
import socket
# one or both the following will work depending on your scenario
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
```

Comment: get_host gets me the local IP rather than the virtual host configured by nginx.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

There is another option:

`import requests
server_ip = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip").json()['origin']`

when django start

Answer (score 0):

like：http://127.0.0.1:1024

```
# formate: {scheme}://{host}
host_addr =  request._current_scheme_host
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation to this answer for this question at the age of two years?