# Is there a python module for ip locator

Tags: python

Is there a specific module to python that can be imported to do IP location lookup from within python rather than having to navigate to a site?

Comment: tried to google ? what about `geoip` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard module to do this. However I would suggest using an online API to do this, you'll just need to make a HTTP request to it and parse the response most likely JSON.

ipinfo.io seems like a good service and is free for some scale projects. There documentation explains how to use it in python in detail too.

```
import requests
print requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8').json()
```

Output:

> ```
> {
>   "ip": "8.8.8.8",
>   "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
>   "loc": "37.385999999999996,-122.0838",
>   "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
>   "city": "Mountain View",
>   "region": "California",
>   "country": "US",
>   "phone": 650
> }
> ```

For more info: https://ipinfo.io/developers