# How to get router assigned IP address in python?

Tags: python-3.x, ip, router

I get a `127.0.1.1` address when I use the [`socket` library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166520/2965993).

I'd like to get my router assigned IP address which is `192.168.0.10`. I can find this IP running `ifconfig` on my wifi adapter which is inconsistently named between my PC and my laptop so using `subprocess` is not the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: the second answer (not accepted) there works very fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib

Comment: That worked! It returned a `192` address as intended. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import netifaces
def find_gateway():
      Interfaces= netifaces.interfaces()
      for inter in Interfaces:
           if inter == "wlan0":
                temp_list = []
                Addresses = netifaces.ifaddresses(inter)
                gws = netifaces.gateways()
                temp_list = list (gws['default'][netifaces.AF_INET])
                count =0 
                for item in temp_list:
                      count +=1
                      if count ==1:
                           print (item)
                      else:
                           pass
find_gateway()
```

I hope this gives you what you want 
modules used netifaces (pip install netifaces)