# How to get ip and subnet mask address using python

Tags: python, networking, ip, subnet

how do I get my ip adress and subnet mask from the computer(windows) using python?

Comment: You are asking 2 questions here: 1. How do you get the internal IP and subnet mask in Python. 2. How do you convert an IP + subnet mask to IP/CIDR. I believe both questions have a good duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Answer (score 2):

For you second question, you can do this:

```py
def int_address(address):
    return list(map(int, address.split(".")))

def bit_len(mask):
    return "".join(bin(m)[2:] for m in mask).find('0')

def prefix(mask, ip):
    return ".".join(str(m & i) for m, i in zip(mask, ip))

def cidr(mask, ip):
    mask = int_address(mask)
    ip = int_address(ip)
    return prefix(mask, ip)+"/"+str(bit_len(mask))

print(cidr("255.255.255.0", "10.0.0.1"))
```

The `bit_len` is a bit hacky, I think a better solution can be found.