# Python websockets server works on localhost but not on server

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I made a basic chat client and server using python websockets, ran it on my pc and it worked completely fine, when I uploaded it to my windows server machine (which has the port '12345' forwarded) and tried to access it using a client from my pc I got a ConnectionRefusedError

I've tried switching to a different port (which was also forwarded) but it didn't change the result

The client (this is the bit that caused the error)

```py
ip = input("IP Address: ")
port = int(input("Port: "))
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ip, port))
```

The server

```py
def open_socket(PORT:int, MAX_USERS:int):
    new_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ("localhost", PORT)
    new_socket.bind(server_address)
    new_socket.listen(MAX_USERS)
    return new_socket
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 24, in <module>
    sock.connect((ip, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

**EDIT**: After trying out Jin's answer I'm now getting a timeout error at the same place (line 24 in client.py)
**EDIT #2**: It is now working! I changed the port to the original one (12345) and I successfully connected to the server!

Comment: Make sure, you have defined the outbound connection to the specific remote address.

Comment: you can't use `localhost` because this address can access only program running on the same computer. Try `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Even though you changed a port forward config in your router, you still need to check whether your server is accepting incoming traffic in the firewall setting. You can do this from Control Panel-Security or Windows Firewall (Sorry I don't remember the exact name of the menu of the Windows).
2. You should bind your `IP` with the socket, not `localhost`. You would want to programmatically get your IP address, rather than using hard-coded one. The followed link would help.

[Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)