# Python: How to print the local DNS Address ONLY?

Tags: python, dns, nslookup

when I type in **nslookup** in cmd I get this output:

**Default Server**: my server name.

**Address**: 192.168.2.1

I would like to use Python to output ONLY the DNS address. Just the number. How can I do that?

This is what I tried, but it opens up cmd again...

```
import os
print (os.system("nslookup"))
```

The output of print should be something like "192.168.2.1" ONLY.

Comment: `os.system('ipconfig /all | findstr /R "DNS\ Servers')` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you. No, because that doesn't output the DNS. It just says 0.

Comment: Check this question:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Comment: `print(os.system("hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1"))` will get just the local ip - not sure how to suppress the extra line for the exit status of zero.