# how to get Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi IP Address in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, ip

im currently using this method to show my IP address on python,but i realize this is not IP address i needed

```
hostname = socket.gethostname() 

IPAddr => socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

is there any problem with my code? or is it just a different method to use?

Comment: Public or local ip?

Comment: local ip @Tylerr

Comment: What does `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` return?

Comment: "192.168.56.1" this is what i get,im using this method on publisher and subscriber method and strangly, my Publisher IP and Subsciber IP on other PC is the same @Tylerr

Comment: or am i just get the wrong idea about this whole IP address?

Comment: No, that's just the IP for the virtualbox local adaptor, try my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import socket
def get_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP
```

Then use `get_ip()` to get your ip.

Reference : [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Answer (score 3):

### Windows Specific implementation, runs within 0.1s.

```
def wlan_ip():
    import subprocess
    result=subprocess.run('ipconfig',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,text=True).stdout.lower()
    scan=0
    for i in result.split('\n'):
        if 'wireless' in i: scan=1
        if scan:
            if 'ipv4' in i: return i.split(':')[1].strip()
print(wlan_ip()) #usually 192.168.0.(DHCP assigned ip)
```

### console OUTPUT for command 'ipconfig':

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f485:4a6a:e7d5:1b1c%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.131 #<-Returns this part

   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works well on windows. How about linux or mac?

Answer (score 2):

Get Ip address

```
import netifaces
netifaces.gateways()
iface = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1]

ip = netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']

print(ip)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me but i changed 'wireless' to 'wi-fi' because the output changes to "Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Wi-Fi" in Spanish Windows.
This code would be more international

```
    for i in result.split('\n'):
        if 'wi-fi' in i: scan=1
```

Thanks mate!!