# Python find IP address which is also shown to online websites

Tags: python, ip

I want to find out my computer’s IP address which other online services access. I have tried following pieces of code from [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

```
import socket
print("\nYour IP Address is: ",end="")
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))


import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()

import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
try:
    # doesn't even have to be reachable
    s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
    IP = s.getsockname()[0]
except:
    IP = '127.0.0.1'
finally:
    s.close()
print(IP)
```

However, the first two return: 10.105.220.74 and the third returns 127.0.1.1.
However, 192.31.105.231 is returned when using https://get-myip.com/ and https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address.

> https://whatismyipaddress.com/ returns: IPv6:
>   2607:f140:6000:17:f0b8:ba78:a9df:213 IPv4: Not detected

Note that I slightly adjusted the IP addresses for privacy reasons.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can't get your public address on the local machine when you're behind a NAT router. You need to get it from an outside service.

Comment: Is there an external API that allows me to get my public address?

Comment: Google "public ip api" there are many

Comment: @Barmar can you help me with finding a suitable API? I researched and only found APIs that could look up the public IP of a website but not of my own machine

Comment: The first two hits I got were for [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/) and [WhatIsMyAddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/api) The first looks very simple.