# How to get local ip address python?

Tags: python, sockets, localhost, python-sockets, local-network

There's a code I found in internet that says it gives my machines local network IP address:

```
hostname = socket.gethostname()
local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

but the IP it returns is 192.168.94.2 but my IP address in WIFI network is actually 192.168.1.107
How can I only get wifi network local IP address with only python?
I want it to work for windows,linux and macos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Comment: No, actually I've tried it too, but it also gives me the wrong IP address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
import socket
hostname = socket.getfqdn()
print("IP Address:",socket.gethostbyname_ex(hostname)[2][1])
```

or this to get public ip:

```
import requests
import json
print(json.loads(requests.get("https://ip.seeip.org/jsonip?").text)["ip"])
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks

Comment: Modified last index 1 to 0, to work on my setup: socket.gethostbyname_ex(hostname)[2][0]

Comment: On Raspberry Pi, it only gets the trivial IP 127.0.1.1

Comment: It doesn't work on MacOS either. says 127.0.0.1