# Log worker ID when using PySpark UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, databricks

I have a compute-heavy Python function that wrap into a PySpark UDF and run on about 100 rows of data. When looking at CPU utilization, it looks like some worker nodes are not even utilized. I realize that this could have a multitude of reasons, and am trying to debug this.

Inside the UDF, I am already logging various statistics (e.g. start and finish time of each UDF execution). Is there any way to log the worker node ID as well? The intention being that I want to make sure that the jobs are evenly distributed between all worker nodes.

I guess IP of the worker or any other unique feature that I can log inside the UDF would work as well.

Comment: not worker ID, but how about its network address or its hostname? You can somewhat refer them with Spark UI

Comment: Do you know how I would do that? I cannot find a single thread on stackoverflow or elsewhere where it describes how to read that info from inside the executor process...

Comment: In Azure Databricks, I adopted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166589/13106037) to get the IP of the worker node in an executing UDF.

Comment: @Thomas you can try this https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/get-ip-address-python/

Comment: thanks! One of them worked, I will add an answer for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
import socket

def my_udf_func(params):
    # your code here
    host = socket.gethostname()
```

You can then either return `host` inside the return parameter (e.g. in a dict) or write it to your logs. Host name provided by databricks is the name of the cluster + the ip address of the worker node, example:

> 0927-152944-dorky406-10-20-136-4

`10-20-136-4` in this case is the IP address.

`socket.getsockname()` seems to be inconsistent - I would not recommend using it.