# How to find IP address of a connected desktop from Android running Python Kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, ip

I have a desktop PC and an Android mobile phone connected to the same Wi-Fi network. The desktop is running a simple java server. The mobile phone is running a simple 'hello world' Python Kivy script. How can the Kivy script finds the IP address of the connected desktop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib

Comment: For discovering services in a local network usually UDP broadcasts are used. There are existing services like Bonjour , UPnP, ... Alternatively if the port is fixed you could scan all IPs in the local network if the port is open and returns the correct response to a certain query.