# How to get the IP of the default interface with Sanic

Tags: python, sanic

Is it possible to get the IP of the default interface with [Sanic](https://sanic.dev/)?

Here is how I do it with Socket. The idea is to do the same thing with Sanic.

```py
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()
IP_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print(IP_address) # 192.168.1.239
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what information you want and how the app is being served (reverse proxy, etc).

Check out these values:

- request.ip (connected interface)
- request.remote_addr (likely what you want https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sanic/api/core.html#sanic.request.Request.remote_addr)
- request.conn_info (object with a bunch of details you may want)

Comment: If I execute `import sanic;print(sanic.request.Request.ip)`, python3 returns an object. Can you tell me how to get the IP in string format from this object?

Comment: You are accessing a method of a class. You need the request instance, which is injected into every route handler. https://sanic.dev/en/guide/basics/handlers.html

Comment: OK, I managed to get the IP in a route with your help. The problem is that I want to start the Sanic server with the correct IP (i.e., not “127.0.0.1”, but something like “192.168.1.239”) with `ip_address = get_ip(); app.run(host=ip_address, port=8000)`, i.e., before any request for a route.

Comment: I think you are confusing the client ip address (the incoming request) and the server ip (something you define in app.run()). Whatever address you pass to app.run is what the server will bind to and what it will receive requests on. Maybe what you want is something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/166506