# How to change the client hostname in FastAPI's TestClient?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I take the IP address using `client.host` from the `Request` object and send this to another function, where I'm using Pydantic's `IPvAnyAddress` to validate the IP address.

Here is my code:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request
from pydantic import IPvAnyAddress


route = APIRouter()


@route.get("/ip-address")
def request_ip_address_deblock_link(request: Request):
    return example_function(request.client.host)

def example_function(ip_address: IPvAnyAddress):
    print(ip_address)
```

But when I'm using FastAPI's `TestClient` to test my API routes, the IP-address check fails, as the hostname in the request is `testclient`.

```
ValueError: 'testclient' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

Is it possible to change the hostname in FastAPI/Starlette's `TestClient`?

Comment: As far as I can tell the _clients_ hostname is hardcoded as `testclient` in `starlette.testclient.TestClient`, but you might be able to go through having a custom `portal_factory` that changes the content of `scope` before using the original `portal_factory`? Also note that the TestClient changed from being based on requests to httpx in the last couple of days, so there might be a slight behavior change here (even if there shouldn't be one).

Comment: @MatsLindh From the source code (cited below), it doesn't seem that `portal_factory` is related to `scope`. Is it?

Comment: @Chris When the portal gets called, it receives `scope` as one of its parameters. But it seems to only happen after the request has happened: https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/bc61505faef15b673bf4bf65db4927daa354d6b8/starlette/testclient.py#L328 - I'm not familiar with the portal, but it's user configurable and has access to `scope` at least somewhere in the request cycle, so that would be my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

From Starlette's source code on `testclient.py` [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/bc61505faef15b673bf4bf65db4927daa354d6b8/starlette/testclient.py#L256)—that FastAPI actually uses under the hood, see [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/6620273083275f7fec446bb3456d3df6582c6813/fastapi/testclient.py#L1))—the `testclient` hostname seems to be fixed/hardcoded.

Hence, you could simply check on server side if `request.client.host == 'testclient'` inside a [Dependency function](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#create-a-dependency-or-dependable) (as @MatsLindh suggested in the comments section), and next, either override `testclient` with [the local IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib), or raise some [exception](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors) (if you like).

Alternatively, you could use the [`HTTPX`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) library, also suggested in the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/#httpx). FastAPI/[Starlette](https://github.com/encode/starlette)'s `TestClient` is now built on `httpx` (see the [relevant commit on github](https://github.com/encode/starlette/commit/6765502c1e5a418c16bb379c54b8ea706b0444cf)).

Comment: Or you could move `get_client_ip_address` out to a dependency with `Depends()` and then override that in the testing context

Answer (score 0):

The `scope["client"]` was changed to `None` on master in Starlette.

After the next release, you should not have any issue.

Disclaimer: Starlette maintainer.

Comment: I am running starlette 0.36.3 and is set to None. Do I understand correctly that should be corectly populated? What release fixes that? I don't see that in release notes up to 0.37.1