# How to get IP address for test in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework, ip-address

I need to get IP Address of current user to use it in test. verify it it is the same in app table.
how to get IP address?

Did not find anything about it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Evaluate](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword and treat is as a python problem. Using solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib) your solution can look something like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***

Example 
    ${ip}=    Evaluate    [l for l in ([ip for ip in socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] if not ip.startswith("127.")][:1], [[(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]]) if l][0][0]    socket
    Log    ${ip}
```