# How to get system hostname in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My host is 10.13.17.18 but my host name is getting some other value

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
```

[image: Host name]

Is there any solution in python to get hostname

Comment: You can try `platform` package and `hostname = platform.node()`

Comment: If there is an answer, it's there: [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess

host = subprocess.getoutput("hostname")
print("host:",host)
```